# Equation $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{2013}$ in rationals

Tags: number-theory

Consider the equation $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{2013}$, where $x,y,z$ are rational numbers. Are there any solutions other than the trivial ones $(2013,0,0),(0,2013,0),(0,0,2013)$?

We can subtract $\sqrt{z}$ from both sides and square to get $x+y+2\sqrt{xy}=2013+z-2\sqrt{2013z}$. To get rid of the square roots I should put them together on one side (and everything else on the other side) and square again, and then square yet again. Is there some other way to solve this equation?

Comment: In general, for any positive rationals $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+b+c=1$, you have a solution $(x,y,z)=(2013a^2,2013b^2,2013c^2)$.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Just wondering, is there a tradition that contest problems include the integer that represents the current year in the problem?

Comment: @Sid, in my experience, yes.  Look at, say, the [Putnam Competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lowell_Putnam_Mathematical_Competition).  For example, see problems A-1 and B-4 of the [2011 contest](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~kedlaya/putnam-backup/2011.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, for any non-negative rationals $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+b+c=1$, you have a solution $(x,y,z)=(2013a^2,2013b^2,2013c^2)$. This is the only family of solutions.  Dividing through by $\sqrt{2013}$ gives
$$
\sqrt{\frac{x}{2013}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{2013}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{2013}}=1.
$$
Each square root is either rational (if the numerator is $2013a^2$) or of the form $x'\sqrt{p'/q'}$, where $x'$ is a positive rational and $p'$ and $q'$ are square-free integers with no common factor.  But if any value of the latter form appears, it can't be made to disappear by adding more rationals or values of the same form.